# Adding vertical separators in JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, swingbuilder

I have create a GUI using Java Swing (Windows Builder Pro) for a personal project and it has a `JToolBar`. I have added separators between the buttons in the tool bar.

```
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.setToolTipText("Save");
    btnSave.setMnemonic('S');
    btnSave.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/org/dbhaskaran/resources/Save32.png")));
    toolBar.add(btnSave);
    toolBar.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));

    JButton btnDesign = new JButton("Design");
    btnDesign.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/org/dbhaskaran/resources/wizard32.png")));
    toolBar.add(btnDesign);
    toolBar.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
```

1. I don't understand why my `JButtons` are getting aligned to the right after adding the separator? And how do I fix it?
2. When I click on one of the buttons on the tool bar, it leaves behind an ugly border - is there any way to get rid of it? Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would see you get better help sooner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only need to figure out if there is a way to get rid of the ugly
>   button border that is left behind on the most recently used Jbutton in
>   the JToolBar.

```
button.setFocusPainted(false)
```

repeat for all `JButtons`

Answer (score 8):

Figured out the answer to my first question:

Replace

```
toolBar.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
```

With

```
toolBar.addSeparator();
```

Now all the Icons in the tool bar are tightly packed. Only need to figure out if there is a way to get rid of the ugly button border that is left behind on the most recently used Jbutton in the JToolBar.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I don't have addSeparator() in Swing